# Starting investing in the UK or German stock market?

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, stock-markets, starting-out-investing, germany

I am a German citizen but living and working in the UK.
Starting my new job came with a higher financial benefit and stock options. I have never invested before but also don't want to waste this opportunity.
I browsed the questions here on how to start investing. But it seems like investing in Germany and the UK seems to work differently.
Now I am unsure, especially in regard to the Brexit, if I should start on the German or UK stock market.
But I am also not sure if I would need to use my shares on the UK market as they are provided within a UK work contract?

Apologies in advance, if this question is not detailed enough, duplicated, etc. As I am super new to the topic I found it quite hard how to ask the question. So any advice is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "my shares" I assume you mean the shares from your stock options. Your options can be exercised for you, and the resulting shares sold and/or held for you, by the broker of your choice. Your employer should help you understand the option exercise process.

As for investing in general, resources such as [Vanguard](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/why-vanguard/four-simple-principles) and Bogleheads ([DE](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Investing_from_Germany)) ([UK](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Investing_from_the_UK)) are reputable guides for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Your options how to buy your equity funds (or single stocks) are certainly limited by your individual situation.
I assume you're being paid in GBP to a UK account. So you might rather choose a British broker (in terms of custodian bank that manages your stock depot). This way you avoid transfers to a German bank and any currency exchange fees.
A British broker will certainly offer lower fees on British stock exchanges (London?). The exchange you're going to trade on is regardless in the end if you choose to invest into (global) funds and not individual stocks: they are being traded on all major exchanges.

Should you consider to move your financials to Germany later on: I have no knowledge about book-entry transfers from UK to Germany and any fiscal implications. Same applies to double-taxation regarding your investment gains.

A general remark: Your citizenship (or the country where you're working) shouldn't limit your investments. To rephrase it: You should not invest **in** Germany or the UK alone but invest globally in indices like MSCI World, MSCI All-Country World or FTSE All-World - to cover your risks by diversification.

And don't worry about currencies when buying funds! The same fund may be offered in USD, EUR and GBP. It doesn't matter since the stocks it contains have different currencies anyway.

For more general education about investing as a beginner I recommend German [Finanztest](https://www.test.de/thema/anlagestrategie/) (by Stiftung Warentest) and Finanztip (they have a great [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/FinanztipDe/playlists)!)